# Illustrator Move two corners by the same distance?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm starting off with a square, and I want to drag the two bottom corners closer together so that the image will resemble a cup.  Right now, I am dragging each corner separately, and taking a note of how much I am moving the corner so I can apply the same distance to the other corner.  Is there an easier way to do this where I can select both and move them both at the same time?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 or 2015 not sure about CS6 Then You can user Free transform (prespective distort) to move both corner at the same time.
Just click and  drag the anchor point.

Here's the Example:-[image]

Comment: You can select the bottom points and use the scale tool, even if this would't work.